# Issue with active directory attribute import

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, attributes, active-directory

I'm trying to mass update users AD attributes from the script below, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Import-Csv : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is invalid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again.
At line:1 char:11
```

From this script:

```
Import-Csv c:\update.csv | ForEach-Object { Set-QADUser -Identity $_.sAMAccountName -ObjectAttributes @{department={$_.department} ;
company={$_.company} ;
physicalDeliveryOfficeName={$_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName} ;
telephoneNumber={$_.telephoneNumber} ;
wWWHomePage={$_.wWWHomePage} ;homePhone={$_.homePhone};
title={$_.title}}}
```

Any help would very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the CSV file itself. Try doing that by itself without piping it out.

Answer (score 0):

The error came from having trailing blank columns in your CSV file. Import-Csv uses the first row in the CSV as names for the columns (unless you specify otherwise) and when you have blank columns (or at least multiple blank columns) it causes this error as it doesn’t have a valid name for them.